# OpenSSH permission denied (public key)

Tags: ssh

I am currently trying to configure an ssh server that uses key-based authentication instead of a password login. I am required to disable the following: `AllowTCPForwarding`, `GatewayPorts`, `PermitRootLogin`, `HostbasedAuthentication`, `PermitEmptyPasswords`, and `X11Forwarding`.

I have followed many tutorials on how to do this, however, when I try to log on to the SSH server I am greeted with

> Permission denied (publickey).

I have already created the  key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` and copied it to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the SSH server, as well as enabled `PubKeyAuthentication` and restarted the server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `ssh` with multiple `-v` flags to get a (very) verbose description of what is happening between client and server. At the very least, this will give you the relevant error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify on the client side which key to use.

You can do this either with `ssh -i PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY`, or via a configuration file, the latter being much more convenient.

Here's an excerpt from my `~/.ssh/config` which applies to github:

```
Host github github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    PasswordAuthentication no
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github.shaggyrogers.rsa
```

Note that words immediately following `Host` are the hostnames (as entered on the command line) that the configuration block applies to. In this case, I can simply type `ssh github` or `ssh github.com`. See `man ssh_config` for more information.